# E-mail result of 'select' statement having multiple rows as result set in ORACLE

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am new to ORACLE PL/SQL world. I am trying to figure out a way to calculate something as below.

Let's say you have a **MASTER_TABLE** as below :

```
SELECT * FROM MASTER_TABLE;
```

```
+----------+----------+------------------+-----------------------+
|  SCHEMA  | TABLE_NM | REQUIRED_COLUMNS |     TABLE_FILTER      |
+----------+----------+------------------+-----------------------+
| USER_SCH | A        | A1,A2,A3         | EXAM_DT > SYSDATE - 1 |
| USER_SCH | B        | B1,B2            | TRUNC(SYSDATE)        |
+----------+----------+------------------+-----------------------+
```

I would like to generate `SELECT` query from above table such as below:

```
SELECT 'SELECT SCHEMA || '.' || TABLE_NM ||' WHERE '|| TABLE_FILTER FROM MASTER_TABLE;
```

Obviously, the result of above query would generate multiple `select` statements.
Now, I want to execute all such `SELECT` statements and send out the resultset via e-mail.

The tricky part is, the columns mentioned in the `MASTER_TABLE` varies (i.e. For table 'A' there can be 3 `REQUIRED_COLUMNS` to be selected, For table 'B' there can be 2 `REQUIRED_COLUMNS` to be selected - As shown in the `MASTER_TABLE`)

I have the e-mail utility ready which basically takes an argument as **your_message** and sends it out via e-mail.

Here is what I have tried :

- Created CURSOR to generate such `select` statements.
- Tried inserting the resultset (`LIST OF SELECT QUERIES`) to another temp table by concatenating the columns. 
  (i.e.

```
 SELECT
    'SELECT '
    || replace(required_columns, ',', '||'',''||')
    || ' AS MSG_BDY'
    || ' FROM '
    || schema
    || '.'
    || table_nm
    || ' WHERE '
    || table_filter
as my_select_stmt
FROM
    master_table;
```

I am stuck after this.

Can you please help me out ? or is there any approach to achieve this ?.

**Note** : Tables mentioned in **MASTER_TABLE** can have 1 or more rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have your tables so I used Scott's.

Master table:

```
SQL> select * From master_table;

SCHEM TABL REQUIRED_COLUMN TABLE_FILTER
----- ---- --------------- ----------------------
scott emp  ename, job, sal hiredate < sysdate - 1
scott dept dname, loc      deptno = 20

SQL>
```

Procedure which simulates your mailing procedure; I'll just display those values.

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_mail (par_result IN SYS.odcivarchar2list)
  2  AS
  3  BEGIN
  4     FOR i IN par_result.FIRST .. par_result.LAST
  5     LOOP
  6        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (par_result (i));
  7     END LOOP;
  8  END;
  9  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
```

Procedure you actually need; as you composed the `select` statement(s), now you only have to run them. In order to do so, use dynamic SQL (e.g. `execute immediate`):

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SQL>
SQL> DECLARE
  2     retval  SYS.odcivarchar2list;
  3  BEGIN
  4     FOR cur_r
  5        IN (SELECT    'SELECT '
  6                   || REPLACE (required_columns, ',', '||'',''||')
  7                   || ' AS MSG_BDY'
  8                   || ' FROM '
  9                   || schema
 10                   || '.'
 11                   || table_nm
 12                   || ' WHERE '
 13                   || table_filter
 14                      AS my_select_stmt
 15              FROM master_table)
 16     LOOP
 17        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE cur_r.my_select_stmt BULK COLLECT INTO retval;
 18
 19        -- you'd call your mailing procedure here
 20        p_mail (retval);
 21     END LOOP;
 22  END;
 23  /
SMITH,CLERK,920
ALLEN,SALESMAN,1600
WARD,SALESMAN,1250
JONES,MANAGER,2975
MARTIN,SALESMAN,1250
BLAKE,MANAGER,2850
CLARK,MANAGER,2450
SCOTT,ANALYST,3000
KING,PRESIDENT,10000
TURNER,SALESMAN,1500
ADAMS,CLERK,1300
JAMES,CLERK,950
FORD,ANALYST,3000
MILLER,CLERK,1300
RESEARCH,DALLAS

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

**[EDIT: what if you wanted to display 'null' for missing values?]**

Well, that's a new moment - probably not very simple. See if this helps.

In order to help myself, I modified `master_table` and added `ID` column to uniquely identify every row. It'll be used to split required columns' list to rows, apply `NVL` to them, apply `CAST` to columns (because `NVL` complains if datatypes don't match), aggregate them back using `listagg`. As this is quite a lot to do, I'm going to create a **view** and use it instead of the table itself.

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v_master_table
  2  AS
  3       SELECT id,
  4              schema,
  5              table_nm,
  6              LISTAGG ('NVL(cast(' || col || ' as varchar2(20)), ''null'')', '||'',''||')
  7                 WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY lvl)
  8                 required_columns,
  9              table_filter
 10         FROM (SELECT id,
 11                      schema,
 12                      table_nm,
 13                      table_filter,
 14                      COLUMN_VALUE lvl,
 15                      TRIM (REGEXP_SUBSTR (required_columns,
 16                                           '[^,]+',
 17                                           1,
 18                                           COLUMN_VALUE))
 19                         col
 20                 FROM master_table
 21                      CROSS JOIN
 22                      TABLE (
 23                         CAST (
 24                            MULTISET (
 25                                   SELECT LEVEL
 26                                     FROM DUAL
 27                               CONNECT BY LEVEL <=
 28                                               REGEXP_COUNT (required_columns,
 29                                                             ',')
 30                                             + 1) AS SYS.odcinumberlist)))
 31     GROUP BY id,
 32              schema,
 33              table_nm,
 34              table_filter;

View created.
```

For example, it now looks like this:

```
SQL> select * from v_master_table where id = 2;

 ID SCHEM TABL REQUIRED_COLUMNS                                                                      TABLE_FILTER
--- ----- ---- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ------------
  2 scott dept NVL(cast(dname as varchar2(20)), 'null')||','||NVL(cast(loc as varchar2(20)), 'null') deptno = 20

SQL>
```

The *mailing* procedure remains the same, no change.

Anonymous PL/SQL block is slightly changed - I removed `REPLACE` you previously used as view does it now; also, source is the view, not the table.

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> DECLARE
  2     retval  SYS.odcivarchar2list;
  3  BEGIN
  4     FOR cur_r
  5        IN (SELECT    'SELECT '
  6                   || required_columns
  7                   || ' AS MSG_BDY'
  8                   || ' FROM '
  9                   || schema
 10                   || '.'
 11                   || table_nm
 12                   || ' WHERE '
 13                   || table_filter
 14                      AS my_select_stmt
 15              FROM v_master_table)
 16     LOOP
 17        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE cur_r.my_select_stmt BULK COLLECT INTO retval;
 18
 19        -- you'd call your mailing procedure here
 20        p_mail (retval);
 21     END LOOP;
 22  END;
 23  /
CLARK,09.06.1981,null
KING,17.11.1981,null
MILLER,23.01.1982,null
RESEARCH,DALLAS

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you. Assuming this could work, what if there are Null values in the resultset and i want them to show as 'NULL'.

Comment: I tried 'NVL' but that has to be applied at the column level, here columns are defined as 'a1,a2,a3'  - CSV values. In this scenario, par_result (i) is going to have CSV values - and if 'a2 or a3' is null, it would be shown as (i.e. 'CLARK,,') that is something I want to avoid. Can you help me out here ?

Comment: This new approach you provided, is perfect. Thank you so much for this.